# Pandas Append Not Working

Tags: python, pandas

```
datum = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'result-title'})
for data in datum:
    print(data.text)
    print(data.get('href'))
    df = {'Title': data.text, 'Url': data.get('href')}
    houseitems.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

What is wrong with my Code? Why when I asked for my houseitems, it gives me empty data.

Empty DataFrame

```
Columns: [Title, Url, Price]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Problem is you need assign back appended `DataFrame`, because pandas [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) **NOT** working inplace like pure python `append`.

It seem you want append to `list`, so parameter `ignore_index=True` is not necessary:

Loop solution:

```
houseitems = []
for data in datum:
    print(data.text)
    print(data.get('href'))
    df = {'Title': data.text, 'Url': data.get('href')}
    houseitems.append(df)
```

Or `list comprehension` solution:

```
houseitems = [{'Title': data.text, 'Url': data.get('href')} for data in datum]
```

And then create `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(houseitems)
```

Comment: houseitems = houseitems.append(df, ignore_index=True) is missing in my code. Documentation says you should store manually.

Answer (score 96):

Try modify line in your code

```
houseitems.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

as

```
houseitems=houseitems.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: houseitems = houseitems.append(df, ignore_index=True) is missing in my code. Documentation says you should store manually.

Comment: Wow. That is quite annoying that they would use a standard python function but in a different way to how it normally performs. Thanks for helping me realise this.

Comment: Docs could be clearer...it's a trap