# Pandas adding rows to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add more rows or records to my data frame,
let's say it looks like this:

```
ID   age   
44   23
31   25
```

and I have a CSV file stored in another data frame without headers

```
33   55
22   23
29   22
```

now I want a new data frame that looks like this

```
ID   age   
44   23
31   25 
33   55
22   23
29   22
```

I have tried using append and concat but I didn't get the result that I wanted

Comment: In what way did you not get the result that you wanted? What did you get instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Append Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51997818/pandas-append-not-working)

Comment: @Att `append` is now deprecated, `concat` should be used

Comment: Also `ignore_index` is not going to solve the issue, it just helps having a nice index ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `df1`/`df2`, you can use [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) to copy the axis of the first DataFrame, then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = pd.concat([df1, df2.set_axis(df1.columns, axis=1)], ignore_index=True)
```

output:

```
   ID  age
0  44   23
1  31   25
2  33   55
3  22   23
4  29   22
```

*NB. `ignore_index=True` is optional, this is just to avoid having duplicated indices. Without it:*

```
   ID  age
0  44   23
1  31   25
0  33   55
1  22   23
2  29   22
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Your first df will be ‘df’

df_2 = pd.dataframe({“Id”: [33, 22, 29], “Age”: [55, 23, 22]})

df = df.append(df_2, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, and ignore_index if you want.

```
output = pd.concat([df1, df2.set_axis(df1['columns'], axis=1)])
```

Comment: How is this different from the logic of my answer posted 14 min ago? ;) (and actually this is incorrect)

Comment: @mozway. It is my opinion. Please do not go in negative direction